# Loading MOPITT data into QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, remote-sensing, hdf5

I have a problem importing Terra MOPITT data into QGIS (2.18) correctly.
The data is in hdf5(HDFEOS) format. QGIS/GDAL imports the data, but the image is rotated by 90° and shifted.

QGIS error: CRS was undefined: defaulting to CRS EPSG:4326 - WGS 84

[image]

Do you know which CRS I have to use?